# What does lea in this x86-64 code do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

These are the first four lines of a function. I know that the first two lines create a new frame in the stack and are basically 'setup' lines. What do the lea instructions do?

```
40148e: 48 83 ec 18    sub    $0x18,%rsp
401492: 48 89 f2       mov    %rsi,%rdx
401495: 48 8d 4e 04    lea    0x4(%rsi),%rcx
401499: 48 8d 46 14    lea    0x14(%rsi),%rax
```

Comment: The second instruction is not setting `%rbp`...

Comment: You might want to be careful posting this exact ASM given where I think it came from .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lea`, Load Effective Address, puts the computed "memory address" in the result register. So here, `rcx = rsi + 4` and `rax = rsi + 0x14`.

By the way, the second line doesn't really look like it's part of the code that sets up the stack frame, `rsi` is the second argument when using System V AMD64 calling conventions.

Comment: Keep in mind that `lea` doesn't necessarily **have** to be used for computing addresses. Since it doesn't occupy the ALU like normal arithmetic instructions, compilers like to use it to perform simple arithmetic ("simple" = the kind supported by `lea` and addressing modes) when the flags aren't needed.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar why do people keep saying that? `lea` uses an ALU on just about any CPU these days. It is not free. "lea in AGU" used to be a thing in a far and gray past..

Comment: Source: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf  `lea` goes to an AGU on K7, K8, K10, Atom .. and that's about it.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar that explains to me why i see `lea rdx, [rax - 1]` after a `call strlen`. Thanks!